# JS: How to trigger CSS changes on divs based on API information

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, append

I'm working on a project in which I need to record the number of pages that a person has completed in an online journal. For that, I use JavaScript/jQuery to make an API call, then use the data from the call to style a few divs based on which pages have been completed.

```
Here's an example of the API I'm using:
[ {
"userId": 1,
"pagesCompleted": 10 },
{
"userId": 2,
"pagesCompleted": 8 },
{
"userId": 3,
"pagesCompleted": 5 }
]
```

I have to write a function that calls the API, goes through the users, and styles divs based on how many pages have been completed out of 10.

Here's the html I'm working with

```
<div class="pagesFinished"> </div>
```

Here's my JS page

```
function getJournal(userId) {
$.ajax({
        url: apiSource + "journal/users",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {

for (let i = 0 ; i < dataLength; i++) {

let buttonArray =(<button id="one">Page 1</button><button id="two">Page 2</button><button id="three">Page 3</button><button id="four">Page 4</button><button id="four">Page 4</button><button id="five">Page 5</button><button id="six">Page 6</button><button id="seven">Page 7</button><button id="eight">Page 8</button><button id="nine">Page 9</button><button id="ten">Page 10 </button>)

$(".pagesFinished").append(buttonArray);
```

Here's where I need to find a way to loop through the userIdArray, figure out how which pages the users have reached, the style the divs accordingly. If a user had read a particular page, the buttons should appear red.

I did something like :

```
let lastPageCompleted = data[i].lastPageCompleted; //should be 10, 8, 5
$("#page" + lastPageCompleted).css('background-color', 'red');
```

But that only makes the last button red, (aka the 10th, 8th, and 5th buttons). I need all of the buttons that precede them to turn red as well. How can I write a loop that goes backwards and applies the css change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
let lastPageCompleted = data[i].lastPageCompleted; //should be 10, 8, 5

for (let j = 1 ; j <= data[i].lastPageCompleted ; j++){
    $("#page" + j).css('background-color', 'red');
}
```